# Output automatically taken as Input in C

Tags: c

This is simple code. In which I am taking a input, printing it, and taking again and printing it once more.

For the second time it doesn't let me give the input.

Can someone explain why ?

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
char buff[50];

printf("Enter a String\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",buff);

puts(buff);

printf("Enter another String\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",buff);

puts(buff);

return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Enter a String
Hello                  // This I have entered
Hello                  // This is the output
Enter another String
Hello                  // This I haven't entered, It automatically takes this.
```

Comment: please indent the code.  suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   Indenting is preferred as it makes the code much more human readable.  Note always indent with spaces, not tabs, as each editor/word processor  has its' own tab stops/tab width

Comment: use #define MEANINGFUL_NAME (50) and replace the 'magic' number '50' with MEANINGFUL_NAME in the code.   Using magic numbers makes the code much less understandable and makes maintenance/debugging much much more difficult.

Comment: when exiting a program due to an error, do not exit with 0 as 0 means the program worked fine.  suggest using 1 when exiting due to an error.  using 'perror()' rather than 'printf()' when exiting with an error, results in the appropriate error message matching the current errno to be output to stderr.  This makes debug much easier.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",buff);` --> `scanf(" %49[^\n]",buff);`  (drop s, add width, add space

Comment: @chux - This works. Thanks. But I don't understand how. Can you please explain ?

Comment: @harsh vaibhav  [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29779778/2410359) added/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second scanf(), place a space at the beginning of your input specifier:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s",buff);
      ^^^
```

This will *eat* the character that is currently satisfying scanf the second time, and allow you to enter a second string.

Answer (score 3):

Using a different format helps

```
// scanf("%[^\n]s",buff);
scanf(" %49[^\n]",buff);
//              ^ no s
//        ^ width limit
//     ^ consume previous line's leftover \n  (and all white-space)
```

Note that `scanf(" %[^\n]",buff);` does not change `buff` when user enters only `"   \n"`.

But better to use `fgets()`

```
fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
buf[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;  // to remove \n
```